# svn: '.' is not a working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet

I have code downloaded using **TortoiseSVN GUI**. I want to use `svn` commands in batch file. However, **TortoiseSVN** doesn't have `svn` commands except for `TortoiseProc.exe /command:.` So then I downloaded **CollabNet commandline svn** which provides `svn` commands. But now I am getting

```
svn: '.' is not a working copy.
```

I also tried with `TortoiseProc.exe /command`: but I also get

```
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are not in a SVN working directory when executing `TortoiseProc`.

Are you sure that you `cd`'d into a working copy before executing `TortoiseProc`?

Please note that you have to execute the command in folder of the **working copy**, not in a `.svn` directory.

Comment: I got the solution ...I was doing it the wrong way ...I use to go in the .svn dir and the was executing svn info. But the correct method is not to go in .svn dir but be in dir which has .svn dir and then execute svn info

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have downloaded the repository using TortoiseSVN GUI. Did you have any problem while you were doing this? Sometimes, when using svn commands, the operation doesn't end correctly leaving the metadata corrupt. You should try doing another checkout.